# search for a very simple EsperIO Kafka example

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, complex-event-processing, esper

I'm just desperately looking for example code for an Esper CEP Kafka Adapter code. I've already installed Kafka and wrote data to a Kafka topic using a producer and now I want to process it with Esper CEP. Unfortunately the documentation of Esper for the Kafka Adapter is not very meaningful. Does anyone have a very simple example?

**Edit:**

So far I added an adapter and it seems to work. However, I don't know how to read the adapter nor how to link a CEP pattern with this adapter. This is my code so far:

```java
config.addImport(KafkaOutputDefault.class);
Properties props = new Properties();

props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer.class.getName());
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer.class.getName());
props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group.id");

props.put(EsperIOKafkaConfig.INPUT_SUBSCRIBER_CONFIG, EsperIOKafkaInputSubscriberByTopicList.class.getName());
props.put(EsperIOKafkaConfig.TOPICS_CONFIG, "test123");
props.put(EsperIOKafkaConfig.INPUT_PROCESSOR_CONFIG, EsperIOKafkaInputProcessorDefault.class.getName());
props.put(EsperIOKafkaConfig.INPUT_TIMESTAMPEXTRACTOR_CONFIG, EsperIOKafkaInputTimestampExtractorConsumerRecord.class.getName());

Configuration config2 = new Configuration();
config2.addPluginLoader("KafkaInput", EsperIOKafkaInputAdapterPlugin.class.getName(), props, null);

EsperIOKafkaInputAdapter adapter = new EsperIOKafkaInputAdapter(props, "default");
adapter.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. I created a [sample Project](https://github.com/lwluc/Esper-Kafka-Example) you could have a look at, especially the [plain-esper branch](https://github.com/lwluc/Esper-Kafka-Example/tree/plain-esper).

An even more simplified Version would be:

```java
public class KafkaExample implements Runnable {
    private String runtimeURI;

    public KafkaExample(String runtimeURI) {
        this.runtimeURI = runtimeURI;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new KafkaExample("KafkaExample").run();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.getCommon().addImport(KafkaOutputDefault.class);
        configuration.getCommon().addEventType(String.class);

        Properties consumerProps = new Properties();

        // Kafka Consumer Properties
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringDeserializer.class.getName());
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, OffsetResetStrategy.EARLIEST.toString().toLowerCase());

        // EsperIO Kafka Input Adapter Properties
        consumerProps.put(EsperIOKafkaConfig.INPUT_SUBSCRIBER_CONFIG, Consumer.class.getName());
        consumerProps.put(EsperIOKafkaConfig.INPUT_PROCESSOR_CONFIG, InputProcessor.class.getName());
        consumerProps.put(EsperIOKafkaConfig.INPUT_TIMESTAMPEXTRACTOR_CONFIG, EsperIOKafkaInputTimestampExtractorConsumerRecord.class.getName());

        configuration.getRuntime().addPluginLoader("KafkaInput", EsperIOKafkaInputAdapterPlugin.class.getName(), consumerProps, null);

        String stmt = "@name('sampleQuery') select * from String";
        EPCompiled compiled;
        try {
            compiled = EPCompilerProvider.getCompiler().compile(stmt, new CompilerArguments(configuration));
        } catch (EPCompileException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

        EPRuntime runtime = EPRuntimeProvider.getRuntime(runtimeURI, configuration);
        EPDeployment deployment;
        try {
            deployment = runtime.getDeploymentService().deploy(compiled, new DeploymentOptions().setDeploymentId(UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
        } catch (EPDeployException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }

        EPStatement statement = runtime.getDeploymentService().getStatement(deployment.getDeploymentId(), "sampleQuery");

        statement.addListener((newData, oldData, sta, run) -> {
            for (EventBean nd : newData) {
                System.out.println(nd.getUnderlying());
            }
        });

        while (true) {}
    }
}
```

```java
public class Consumer implements EsperIOKafkaInputSubscriber {
    @Override
    public void subscribe(EsperIOKafkaInputSubscriberContext context) {
        Collection<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();
        collection.add("input");
        context.getConsumer().subscribe(collection);
    }
}
```

```java
public class InputProcessor implements EsperIOKafkaInputProcessor {
    private EPRuntime runtime;

    @Override
    public void init(EsperIOKafkaInputProcessorContext context) {
        this.runtime = context.getRuntime();
    }

    @Override
    public void process(ConsumerRecords<Object, Object> records) {
        for (ConsumerRecord record : records) {
            if (record.value() != null) {
                try {
                    runtime.getEventService().sendEventBean(record.value().toString(), "String");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void close() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample code follows. This code assumes there are already some messages in the topic. This does not loop and wait for more messages.

```
    Properties consumerProps = new Properties();
    consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, ip);
    consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    consumerProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "mygroup");
    KafkaConsumer consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerProps);
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> rows = consumer.poll(1000);
    Iterator<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> it = rows.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        ConsumerRecord<String, String> row = it.next();
        MyEvent event = new MyEvent(row.value()); // transform string to event

        // process event
        runtime.sendEvent(event);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't look like what the question is asking for. There's nothing "Esper" specific here

Comment: Thanks for the Kafka consumer but my problem is that I want to recognize patterns from Kafka using Esper CEP. Esper offers an adapter called esperIO Kafka adapter but unfortunately I can't find any simplified examples of how to set up a CEP module in Esper for a Kafka topic.

Comment: Link to a class that uses the adapter...https://github.com/espertechinc/esper/blob/9b477c192853ca85e70f2f9efbb914b6cf94a78d/esperio/esperio-kafka/src/test/java/com/espertech/esperio/kafka/TestKafkaInputMsgTimestampBeanSerValue.java

Comment: This class use the Kafka Producer. Do you mean the TestKafkaOutput.java File?

Comment: This class uses the Kafka producer to send a message that the Kafka input adapter receives. It tests the input adapter by sending a message using a Kafka producer.

Comment: Yes exactly, I have my Kafka producer already - it's only about a Kafka Consumer or to enable a query from ESPER CEP to a certain topic from Kafka.
To be honest, I still don't understand how to integrate an Esper CEP pattern into my consumer or how the pattern monitors the consumer for anomalies. E.g. how I can integrate the pattern into your code shown above.

Comment: @user650839 please, need help.